# What is the chronological order of all the Bond Films based on plot?

Tags: james-bond, chronology

I am curious, plot-wise, what the chronological order of the James Bond films are?

I seem to recall that *Casino Royal* and *Quantum of Solace* are set in the beginning of James' career as a 00-agent and that *Dr. No* is set before he became aware of SPECTRE's existence. But that's about it.

Comment: There simply is ***none***, so just don't try to find or construe one.

Comment: … or you'll get back round to the new Casino Royale & your brain will leak… ;-)

Comment: Do keep in mind that starting with Daniel Craig, Bond is a reboot. So there are really _two_ chronological orders, if any.

Comment: Related: [Is there any continuity between James Bond movies that have different actors portraying the title character?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/is-there-any-continuity-between-james-bond-movies-that-have-different-actors-por)

Answer (score 7):

Film wise (that is, ignoring depictions in television and cameo's), there are 3 continuities.

- The simplest is the standalone [Casino Royale](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061452/). This is a one off
  spoof, but as it was produced by MGM and Cubby Brocolli, must still
  be considered 'official'; despite it's comedic nature.

The next two are more strictly 'canon', although they don't both employ what is known as rolling continuity.

- From *Dr. No* to *Die Another Day*, all the
  Connery/Lazenby/Moore/Dalton/Brosnan films should loosely be
  considered in chronological order in the order they were released.
  This is never explicitly confirmed, but simply the style and
  technology of the films production roughly indicates a progression
  forward of time. It's problematic to be this simplistic, and it also
  negates the fact that for all the films to be in the same continuity
  Bond would likely be pushing 80 by *Die Another Day*.

  There is a fan theory that suggests that 'James Bond' was actually
  another codename (like 007) that is passed from agent to agent, and
  as such they were never meant to be the same person. This is disputed
  by the events of *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*, which actually
  attempts a rolling continuity for the first time. At the end of this
  film, Bond's wife is murdered, and the start of the following film
  begins with Bond standing in front of her grave (despite a change in
  actor), demonstrating a direct causal link between the films.

  *On Her Majesty's Secret Service* also features props from the previous films to assert a continuity, and contradictingly birthed
  the 'Bond is different men' theory with the line "This never happened
  to the other fellow", referring to Bond's previous iteration.
- The final continuity, the Daniel Craig iteration, is the strictest in sense of its's unfolding continuity. These films are linked directly, and follow one another quite obviously.

It's a misnomer to align all the Bond films in any continuity (with the exception of the Craig franchise), as most of the Connery-Brosnan years only referenced each other playingly and for humour, instead of the construction of a plot.

This is a tradition that continues into the Craig franchise, wherein the ejector seat Aston Martin from *Goldfinger* shows up in *Skyfall*. It's simply a knowing nod to the audience, it isn't supposed to assert that Daniel Craig's Bond has previously been present in the events of *Goldfinger*.

Comment: Excellent summary. Just one little remark: Are you sure that Bond stands a his late wife's grave in the movie following *OHMSS* (which would have been either *Diamonds Are Forever* or *Live and Let Die*, depending on your viewpoint)? I think you mean the scene from the much later *For Your Eyes Only* (as also alluded in [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/43358/49)). I might be wrong, though since I'm admittedly not that well versed in *Diamonds Are Forever*. By the way, her death is also mentioned shortly in Dalton's *License To Kill*.

Comment: Interestingly, I once heard that they initially wanted to come up with some plastic surgery background for *OHMSS*, given that it was their first actor change. Fortunately they didn't go through with this, though, as that could have gone quite annoying for the 5th time.

Comment: Daniel Craig's film share a """"continuity"""" with the non-spoof films, as Dame Judi Dench plays M from *GoldenEye* right up until *Skyfall*.

Comment: @DrRDizzle I don't think you can base an actual continuity (no matter behind how many quotes) on the mere presence of the same actor. The Craig films are obviously pure reboot's without any backward continuity at all.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Between characters reappearing and nods towards previous films in the series, Craig's films are only as non-canon as any other Bond films have ever been - which is why this question is, in effect, meaningless. Continuity is difficult to establish when, for the most part, it has never mattered to the series.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Indeed. Then why confuse matters by deducing a continuity from Judi Dench's presence?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Because Daniel Craig's run is no more or less a reboot than Roger Moore's - it is just the latest set of films in a franchise that has no notion of continuity. It cannot be said that Craig does or does not share a canon with Moore, no more than it can be said that Moore shares a canon with Connery. It simply isn't something the series cares about, and as such trying to class Craig's run as a separate continuity when it has just as much evidence to claim it as part of the main "canon" is... strange.

Comment: @DrRDizzle So that Judi Dench statement was meant entirely sarcastic then? In this case excuse my confusion. You are right that there is *zero* continuity to be derived from it then. Though, the Craig run has way less evidence to claim a connection to the other films, seeing how it depicts the actual start of his carreer and is in itself tied with a strong continuty, in contrast to all the other films.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson More as a way of pointing out why it makes little sense to try and divide the Craig films from the others, and how little sense trying to parse the "canon" of the Bond film actually makes.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Meh, still makes pretty much sense to separate the Craig films from the others, given all the factors like depicting the start of his carreer like no other film did before or having a strongly connected story continuity like no other film before. Besides that at the bottom line the answer already explicitly says that there is no actual continuity for all the films and trying to find one is a flawed premise (and I wouldn't have upvoted it at all if hadn't said this). So what is this answer still missing for you?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson It isn't missing anything, I just think that trying to separate the Craig films out from the others is... redundant.

Comment: @DrRDizzle, the Craig films are clearly setting up a different proposition to their predecessors. They directly link from each other, in a way that has only ever been gestured to with the previous films (hence their separation) . It's obvious they are attempting to pull off a more cohesive continuity.

Answer (score 1):

You must also take into account that Thunderball the book was made as Thunderball the movie, and was also made as Never Say Never Again, both staring Sean Connery (the reasons why are long & legal, but basically, the writer of the first film script left, but still retained film rights to his script, which was made into a film years later). Just to complicate matters, there have been also more than one Casino Royale (1 with Daniel Craig, 1 with David Niven, and an earlier one too produced by an American television company as a made for television play).

As such, I'd offer that one should use the order of the Flemming books, and ignore the films, as they were not produced in order.