# Why wasn't Teresa Bond's tombstone written as Tracy Bond?

Tags: james-bond, for-your-eyes-only

James Bond was married to [Teresa "Tracy" Bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy_Bond) in the film *[On Her Majesty's Secret Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy_Bond)*.

Teresa was adamant that James referred to her as *Tracy* and NOT *Teresa*:

> Tracy:  Teresa was a saint. I'm known as Tracy.
>
> James:  Well, Tracy, next time.

James Bond also corrects her father when he refers to her as Teresa:

> Draco:  I am also Teresa's father.
>
> James:  Tracy?
>
> Draco:  Yes, Tracy. Tracy.

The last thing that James Bond tells Tracy is that "We have all the time in the world" at the end of *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*.

James Bond is seen laying flowers on her tombstone in the film [*For Your Eyes* *Only*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Your_Eyes_Only_(film)).

Teresa Bond's tombstone is a personal sentiment by James Bond to her.  The tombstone is sure to say "Beloved wife of James Bond" as well as the phrase "We have all the time in the world".

Since James Bond always referred to her as Tracy and she preferred that name, is there any evidence or reference from any Bond film on why the tombstone would read *Teresa Bond* rather than *Tracy Bond*?

[image: Teresa Bond Tombstone]

Comment: Pure speculation, but surely the line about Teresa being "the name of a saint" would be a good reason to use it on her gravestone

Comment: I know, but that's the exact reason that she wanted to be referred to as Tracy and not Teresa.

Comment: Yes, but now she's dead she can hardly argue about it :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's why Bond should have honored her wishes.  He holds her in such high esteem.  I just always thought it was bizarre that he didn't put that name on her tombstone.  But, I am a girl, maybe I think differently :)

Comment: I can see the poetic irony. Teresa is a saints name and now she's with the saints.

Comment: Yeah, maybe.  She was hardly a saint while alive though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certain rules in relation to what can be put on gravestones. 
Though these differ by authorities/ Diocese.

The Diocese of Oxford, for example, says that

> "inscriptions must be simple, reverent and theologically acceptable;
>   they may include appropriate quotations from the scriptures or
>   literary sources." Nicknames or pet names are allowed, but in inverted
>   commas.

Full rules pertaining to The Diocese of Oxford and burials can be seen [here](http://www.oxford.anglican.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Churchyard-Regulations-Updated-2009.pdf) specifically section 4.6

If a similar rule was in place here the gravestone would need to read Teresa "Tracy" Bond - and the gravestone simply isnt big enough to accomodate this.

Other Diocese such as Birmingham ban nicknames in their totality and state that the name "as is displayed on their Birth Certificate should be used"

Here is a link showing this ruling being upheld [Judge upholds ban on nicknames](http://www.birminghammail.co.uk/news/local-news/church-of-england-judge-rules-nicknames-65779)

If the graveyard was under regulations such of this then Tracy would not be able to be used at all.

Comment: Very interesting.  Great answer.  Could you possibly provide a link for the Diocese of Oxford where you got your quote and I will accept answer.  Thanks :)

Comment: @steelerfan added

Comment: I would think the stated intent of the rule could have best been upheld by allowing, in the linked case "[small print] Rodney William Lawton Stone [next line] known as [next line, big print] ROD STONE".  That would help people doing genealogy research, not only to correlate the grave marker with the birth certificate, but also to correlate it with the name Rod Stone used elsewhere.  The size of text needed to fit the full name on one line would be smaller than ideal for visitors trying to locate the headstone; having the short form in big text would make the stone easier to find.